# Seeing SSL Handshake timeouts from Gatling V2 and also V3

Tags: scala, performance, http, ssl, gatling

this is happening on higher loads and is not prevalent in lower RPS values. So, when we tried to generate more than 50RPS load from Gatling via both local and EC2 machines. we are seeing SSL handshake failures and the response times are exponentially increasing. Did anyone face this issue before via Gatling?

```
07:34:32.270 [DEBUG] i.g.h.a.AsyncHandler - Request  failed for user 166
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source)
Wrapped by: java.net.ConnectException: handshake timed out
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:168)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.channel.NettyConnectListener$1.onFailure(NettyConnectListener.java:139)
    at org.asynchttpclient.netty.SimpleFutureListener.operationComplete(SimpleFutureListener.java:26)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:512)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:505)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:484)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:425)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.notifyHandshakeFailure(SslHandler.java:1488)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.access$1100(SslHandler.java:162)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$5.run(SslHandler.java:1672)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:120)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:399)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:464)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: can you share with us more details about this issue, like the technology you use and when this issue happened and more...

Answer (score 1):

Don't blame the messenger, here Gatling. These errors really means that your server fails to perform its part of the TLS handshake in due time.
You have to investigate your network and your technology responsible to server-side TLS.

Note: Gatling 2 has been dead for almost 5 years. You should really upgrade to Gatling 3.8.